# Getting All Post From Specific category in wpdb

Tags: categories, wpdb

Please I am a bit frustrated. I am trying to get all post from specific a category id from wpdb below is my code. I dont Know where I am getting it wrong.

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified_gmt
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN  $wpdb->term_relationships  as t
        ON ID = t.object_id
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND t.term_taxonomy_id = 3
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_password = ''
    AND post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY post_type DESC, post_modified DESC
    LIMIT 10"
);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `$wpdb` and not just a normal `WP_Query` or `get_posts()`?

Comment: Yes there is reason, I am using it as xml sitemap for a particular category

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda and how is that a reason?

Comment: Are there really 2 where clauses in your code?

Comment: I want to use it to create an xml sitemap from a particular category.

My code is duplicate, but after I remove it, it does not solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are many things that are not exactly correct with your code:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified_gmt
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN  $wpdb->term_relationships  as t
        ON ID = t.object_id
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND t.term_taxonomy_id = 3
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'  # <-- !! second WHERE clause
    AND post_password = ''
    AND post_type = 'post'  # <-- !! you've already used this condition
    ORDER BY post_type DESC, post_modified DESC  # <-- !! why do you order by post_type if you select only posts??
    LIMIT 10"
);
```

### So how to write it in a nicer way?

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_modified_gmt
     FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} as t  # <-- you can use INNER JOIN in here, since you want posts from category, so every post has to have some term assigned to it
        ON (p.ID = t.object_id)
     WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_password = '' AND t.term_taxonomy_id = %d
     ORDER BY p.post_modified_gmt DESC
     LIMIT 10",
     3  // <-- Notice: you'll have to use term_taxonomy_id and not term_id in here
));
```

Comment: I guess you are referring to /wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID= **3** as term_taxonomy_id.

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda No, that is term_id and it can be different from term_taxonomy_id (that’s why it would be much better if you used WP_Query to get these posts)

Comment: So how can I use WP_Query to get the post ?

Comment: I found this code `SELECT termtax.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_terms AS terms JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS termtax ON terms.term_id = termtax.term_id WHERE terms.name = "My category" `

Is there anyway I can use it to acheive my goal of getting Post from a specific category ?